# wordpress server certificate does not match url

Tags: certificates

When visiting a WordPress blog using HTTPS Chrome gives me a warning that the domain on the certificate (`*.wordpress.com`) does not match the URL (`someguysblog.com`).

This seems to be a [known issue](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/site-host-name-does-not-match-your-ssl-certificate). So is there any way to whitelist this URL in chrome? And should/could I just whitelist all urls with this type of wordpress domain certificate?

(In case it is important, the certificate is signed by `Go Daddy G2`, which appears in my list of trusted root authorities in chrome settings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an exception in your browser like it isbdescribed here:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/https/

You just have to import their certificate and trust it.

wordpress.com does not support SSL certificates for mapped domains. This is well known. Normally you do not need https when visiting a public wordpress.com website. They generally use it for login to the backend.

Visitors can try to access the website with http instead of https or add the certificate to the browser and trust it.

https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/ssl-and-security-certificates?replies=1

Comment: so it is safe to trust all sites in the wordpress domain with that certificate?

Comment: Yes, they all use *.wordpress.com as hostname. Importing the *.wordpress.com certificate and trusting it should be fine.

Comment: thanks, I also noticed the guide in that link for chrome is a bit outdated. You can't drag-n-drop the certificate to save it (need right click). After saving the certificate I can just go to chrome settings->ssl/tls->manage certificates and import it.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if we can actually trust all wordpress.com sites...They must have quite limited functionality if you're saying you can blindly trust all of them.

Comment: Well it is an issue on the side of wordpress.com with their configuration: "SSL certificates need to be signed to a specific domain, and we can’t provide certificates for every mapped domain, so our certificate is signed for WordPress.com." It seems this is the only viable solution at the moment because the mapped domains on wordpress.com resolve to *.wordpress.com as host. They already use a SSL certificate for *.wordpress.com. For example GitHub has not this problem because they use CName and map the domains correctly.

Comment: What you are suggesting is very risky Daniel. @jiggunjer, see my answer for details.

Comment: This is the official recommendation of wordpress.com (see the linked article). I know that they should not suggest this and better fix their configuration.

Comment: Daniel - I'm surprised that you recommend a security practice that you know is wrong. I don't think that is appropriate for this site.

Comment: Right, I know, and Automattic should know too. But it is their official recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

### Do not do this!

Installing this certificate dramatically reduces the security of SSL for all sites (eg: your bank), not just the Wordpress sites.

If an attacker can redirect your request from a site you intend to access over SSL to any site hosted on Wordpress, your browser will not issue a warning once you have installed the certificate as described. Attacks such as [DNS poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing) and [MiTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) are examples of attacks that would allow this redirection to occur.

Instead of trusting the certificate, you can manually approve the certificate on each access.

Comment: This assumes wordpress doesn't check sites they host for malicious content. Isn't it in their interest to only give certificates to trusted hosts?

Comment: How much can they check @jiggunjer? Are you willing to trust the entirety of your SSL connections to Wordpress's checking? We know that the browser providers don't to do this as if they trusted the cert they'd trust it out of the box.

Comment: I do often manually check what certificate I am using whenever I access a critical site like my bank. So if all of a sudden I see a `*.wordpress.com` cert I'll log the IP and close the browser. I just don't wan't to click through several warnings every time I visit a wordpress blog (theres a lot).

Comment: @jiggunjer - it seems to me that checking the cert for every site you use is more work and much riskier than just manually approving the certs on Wordpress sites. What if you forget to check once when you access your bank? Seems risky to even partially disable SSL security checks to me.

Comment: Could I configure chrome to do an additional check, so when I visit a 'critical' site it warns me if the site is using a certificate from a whitelisted CDN? Then I could have the best of both worlds... like a yellow padlock extension or something :p

Comment: Not that I know of. Firefox tends to have more extensions of this nature.

Comment: Also there is no way to be certain there isn't a MiTM if the url doesn't match the certificate domain. The blogs public key could have been intercepted and a MiTM (hosted by wordpress) would just present the same cert right?